# The meaning of (:- !,) in Prolog

Tags: prolog, prolog-cut

I am a newbie to Prolog and having a hard time understanding the meaning of the cut operator, `!`, in different contexts.

For instance, what is the effect of it in this line here? Or how to read this line in plane English

```
rewrite(p => q, F) :- !, rewrite(~ p or q, F).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be one of several `rewrite/2` predicates.

The cut is intended to mean that *this* is the only rule that handles `p => q` as the first argument, so do *not* backtrack and check the other `rewrite/2` predicates below this one.

Such a cut is useful for performance, and to avoid a "catch-all"/default `rewrite(P, F)` predicate which might exist.

Prolog's debugging features are hugely useful to show what is going on. Start with `trace`, at https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger